# SQL query to find non-matching fields in certain rows

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server table is something like this:

```
ProductRef    ShopID    ShopRef
--------------------------------
ABC              1        bla
ABC              2        
ABC              3        bla
DEF              1        rhu
DEF              2        rhu
XYZ              1        barb
XYZ              2        baxb
XYZ              3        barb
```

The shop ref should be the same for all rows of the same product.

What I need to find is all products where the shop reference is not the same for all shops (ignoring blank shop references which don't matter, they can be considered matching).

So in the above example I would want to return XYZ.  ABC & DEF are fine.
Either all the XYZ rows or just "XYZ" would work.

I can't work out the right way to group it to get this result, the best I've managed so far is the number of matching ShopRef fields per product, which is not helpful as this can vary and still be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductRef
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(ShopRef)), '') <> ''
GROUP BY ProductRef
HAVING MAX(ShopRef) <> MIN(ShopRef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductRef
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ProductRef
HAVING MAX(ShopRef) <> MIN(ShopRef)
```

Comment: "ignoring blank shop references which don't matter, they can be considered matching"

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I add a line to prevent that I will be giving exactly the same solution than you.